# Why this not passing variable from view to controller?

Tags: symfony, twig

Befeore you click minus just write a short answear. Not so many twig advice in the web. I'm beginner.

View

```
#\src\BookBundle\Resources\views\Default\index.html.twig
<a href="{{ path('add',{'name':'John','surname':'Smith'})}}">Add John to DB</a>
```

Controller

```
#\src\BookBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
 /**
 * @Route("/add.html", name="add")
 * @Template()
 */

public function addAction($name,$surname)
{
    //some db code
    return new Response('New name '.$name);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [twig: pass variables from view to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323231/twig-pass-variables-from-view-to-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not definited any slug placeholder for $name and $surname in your route, so `path('add',{'name':'John','surname':'Smith'})` will append the data to the query string. Something like `/add.html?name=John&surname=Smith`. So, you can get those parameters in your controller with `$request->query->get('name');`. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-as-a-controller-argument

Remember that when you use the `@Template` annotation, the controller should return an array of parameters to pass to the view.